# Error convirtiendo jsonp a json en python con la respuesta del API de Pixabay

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonp

Estoy intentado obtener la URL de una imagen para descargarla por linea de comandos desde una respuesta en formato jsonp de pixabay (usndo su API):

Esto es la petición:

```
    import jsonp2json
    import json
    import python_pixabay

    pix = python_pixabay.Pixabay('xxxxxx')

    # default image search
    img_search = pix.image_search()   


    # custom image search
   jsonp_response = pix.image_search(q = 'cats dogs',
                           lang = 'es',
                           response_group = 'high_resolution',
                           image_type = 'photo',
                           orientation = 'horizontal',
                           category = 'animals',
                           safesearch = 'true',
                           order = 'latest',
                           page = 1,
                           per_page = 3)

    print(jsonp_response)
```

La respuesta 'jsonp_response' viene en formato jsonp, así:

```
   {
'totalHits': 156, 
'hits': [   
    {
        'largeImageURL': 'https://pixabay.com/get/....jpg',
        'webformatHeight': 360, 
        'webformatWidth': 640, 
        'likes': 2, 
        'imageWidth': 5184, 
        'id': 3396156, 
        'user_id': 8982455, 
        'views': 280, 
        'comments': 0, 
        'pageURL': 'https://pixabay.com/es/gato-mascota-animales-blanco-3396156/', 
        'imageHeight': 2916, 
        'webformatURL': 'https://pixabay.com/get/....jpg', 
        'type': 'photo', 
        'previewHeight': 84, 
        'tags': 'gato, mascota, animales', 
        'downloads': 126, 
        'user': 'mohdrashidsmc', 
        'favorites': 2, 
        'imageSize': 974885, 
        'previewWidth': 150, 
        'userImageURL': '', 
        'previewURL': 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/13/11/40/cat-3396156_150.jpg'
    }, 
    .....
    .....
    .....
] , 'total': 156}
```

En realidad vienen varios de estos en la misma respuesta pero solo he puesto uno aquí para que no sea tan extenso.

También estoy usando un modulo que se llama 'jsonp2json' y en él solo se encuntra esta función.

```
import sys
def convert(jsonp):
    try:
        l_index = jsonp.index('(') + 1
        r_index = jsonp.rindex(')')
    except ValueError:
        print("Input is not in a jsonp format.")
        return

    res = jsonp[l_index:r_index]
    return res
```

Y estoy intentado hacer esto para obtener los datos en json

```
json_result = jsonp2json.convert(jsonp_response)
result = json.loads(json_result)
print(result)
```

Y Estoy obteniendo este error :-(

```
$ py -3 c:/Users/ivan/Desktop/pixabay/get_img.py                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ivan/Desktop/pixabay/get_img.py", line 30, in <module>
    json_result = jsonp2json.convert(jsonp_response)
  File "c:/Users/ivan/Desktop/pixabay/get_img.py", line 7, in convert
    l_index = jsonp.index('(') + 1
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index
```

Pes eso, no tengo claro si el problema está en la variable **jsonp_response** o en la función **convert(jsonp)** ¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?.

Lo ideal sería hacer algo así:

```
print(json_result['largeImageURL'][0])
print(json_result['largeImageURL'][1])
print(json_result['largeImageURL'][2])
```

y obtener una salida como esta

```
'https://pixabay.com/get/0.jpg'
'https://pixabay.com/get/1.jpg'
'https://pixabay.com/get/2.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar esto que soluciona sobradamente todos los problemas que tenia. Aquí lo dejo por si a alguien mas le puede ser útil.

```
hits=img_search.get("hits")
images=[]
for hit in hits:
    largeImageURL = hit['largeImageURL']
    print (largeImageURL)
    images.append (largeImageURL)   
print (images)
```

Fuente:
http://intelligentonlinetools.com/blog/tag/machine-learning/page/2/

Un saludo a todos y gracias!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de averiguar que no es necesario convertir el jsonp a json par obtener la url de la imagen. Es suficiente con hacer esto.

```
url = jsonp_response['hits'][1]['largeImageURL']    
print(url)
```

La solución fue obtenida de aquí
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344708/downloaded-picture-from-pixabay-using-its-api-but-downloaded-image-is-not-suppo

Mil gracias a la existencia de esta maravillosa comunidad, ya sea en español o ingles :-)

Sin embargo, me queda una pregunta ¿Como sé la cantidad de url que contiene la respuesta? Es decir, si tengo esto:

```
url = jsonp_response['hits'][n]['largeImageURL']
```

Cómo sé el valor máximo que puede tener 'n'?

----------------------------------ACTUALIZACIÓN-----------------------------

el Valor de n (número de página) se obtiene así

```
n_pages = len(jsonp_response['hits'])
```

Gracias @FJSevilla por tu respuesta:

De esto surge otra pregunta **¿Como obtener todas las URL de esta página?**

Probé así pero esto me da el tamaño del 'string' de la primera url que se encuentra

```
n_url = len(jsonp_response['hits'][0]['largeImageURL'])
```

Comment: ¿Iván la cantidad de urls no te la da `'totalHits': 156`?, es decir `n = jsonp_response['totalHits']`. De ser así la última url deberías ser `jsonp_response['hits'][jsonp_response['totalHits'] - 1]` dado que los índices en Python empiezan en 0, el primer elemento es `jsonp_response['hits'][0]`

Comment: No, viene mucho menos. Si pongo ese número obtengo este error:     url = cis['hits'][156]['largeImageURL']
**IndexError: list index out of range:** ¿No se puede obtener haciendo algo parecido a esto? for n in cis['hits']:
 for j in cis['hits'][n]:
  cis['hits'][j]['largeImageURL']
  print(URL)

Comment: Como comento 156 no es un índice válido, el máximo sería 155 y el primero es 0 no 1. Dado que aparentemente todo está parseado a objetos Python por el error que muestras en la pregunta (diccionarios y listas) `n = len(jsonp_response['hits'])` también debe funcionar, pero recuerda el último índice es `numero_de_elementos  - 1`.

Comment: Con 155 también tengo ese error: Los acabo de contar a pelo, todas las ocurrencias de **largeImageURL,** y vienen 50 en la respuesta... lo que sería bueno es no tener que contarlos a pelo

Comment: Si hago lo que dices **size = len(jsonp_response['hits'])** me da un valor de **size=3**

Comment: Creo que tiene algo que ver con esto  **page = 1** y                  **per_page = 3** : en la funcion **pix.image_search**  es decir, creo que me está enviando solo la primera página de tres y que cada página contine 50 URL, eso cuadraria mas o menos con **totalHits=156**... aun así ¿No hay forma de saber esto sin tener que contar? :-)